# Nhibernate - Dialect does not support DbType.Double

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, dialect

When I try to execute this query:

```
        var q = session.QueryOver<Member>();
         q.Select(Projections.Avg<Member>(x => x.AccountBalance));
          var result = q.List();
```

I am getting a:

```
Dialect does not support DbType.Double
Parameter name: typecode
```

Any ideas?  I am using a MySQL dialect, and cannot imagine where the query can be wrong as its quite simple.

`AccountBalance` is of type `double`.  I've even tried it with the average of the `ID` field, which is of type long, but still got the same exact error message.

Comment: which version of Nhibernate you using?

Comment: and can you share how are you configuring session factory

Comment: Nhibernate is 3.2 latest, and session factory is configure by code.

Comment: I don't believe MySql has a double type, what happens if you make `AccountBalance` is of type `single` or `decimal`

Comment: I have the same problem:

'session.Query<Event>().GroupBy(x => x.Country.Name).Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Value = x.Sum(y => y.Amount) });'

(Amount is a decimal, the message I get talks about not supporting DbType.Decimal)

the hql: 'select r.Country.Name, sum(r.Amount) from Event r group by r.Country.Name' works fine :/

Answer (score 7):

NHibernate uses cast to ensure return type of `AVG` function.

MySql prior version 5 does not support `NUMERIC` type in `CAST` expression. [The support was added in MySql 5.0.8](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast). So you need to use MySQL5Dialect.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

I don't know if this will help, but as I said above I was having a similar problem.  Upon digging a little further in I discovered that I had been using the NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect (via FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MySQLConfiguration)

To fix my problem I used the MySQL5Dialect instead, i.e.

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard
    .Dialect<MySQL5Dialect>()
    .ConnectionString(connectionString))
```

Hope this helps you as I was really scratching my head on this one...

Answer (score 0):

change the dialect on the config file or bootstrapping